# How can I install the same version of the modules from one Perl installation in another installation, like you can do with pip in Python?

Tags: python, perl

In Python I can use pip to dump a list of versions of installed modules

`pip list > modules.txt`

and use it to install that same list of versions of modules in another installation.

`pip install -r modules.txt`

How is this done with Perl?

(Note: I understand that I can install standalone Perl installations using perlbrew, which makes it the equivalent of Python's virtualenv, so I'm just missing the pip piece.)

Comment: You can do this easily if you're already using perlbrew: http://perlbrew.pl/Reinstall-All-Modules-On-New-Perl.html

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be exactly what I was looking for - off to try it out now, thanks.

Comment: That recipe will install the latest version of all the modules, not the same version that was in the old installation.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know - I'd have had to find out the hard way.  Darn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a CPAN autobundle file. It records the specific version of each module.
2. Use a module installer that can target versions, such Carton, perlrocks, cpanminus. Example: `cpanm HTTP::Negotiate@6.00`